# Send serialized form data as well as other data with jQuery post()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send my form data as well as a page number (for pagination) in a single post(), unfortunately I can't get it working. Here is the code and it doesn't run with the {name : data} tag included. It runs fine with it removed but obviously the pagination doesn't work. Anybody know how I can send the serialized form data as well as some information from a variable?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            //set initial page to zero
        var pageRequest = 0;
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();

        $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
            $('#test_form').submit();
        });

        //assign current page number to variable and get a new page
        $('#page-links').on('click', '.page-indv', function(){
            var pageRequest = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#test_form').submit();});

        //Send form data and page number, recieve JSON results 

        $('#test_form').submit(function(){
            $.post(
                $(this).attr('action'),
                           {pgeNmbr : pageRequest}, //works fine with this line removed
                $(this).serialize(),
                function(data){
                    $('#results').html(data.html);
                    $('#page-links').html(data.page);
                },
                "json"
            );
            return false;
        });
        $('#test_form').submit();
    });
```

Comment: If you already have `click` event - than you can add hidden field on a form and write there current pagination value. Sure, it's not a solution. but still.

Comment: u_mulder, thank you, that's how I had it working, just curious if there was a way to add it to the post data instead of using a hidden field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
..
$(this).serialize()+'&pgeNmbr='+pageRequest
..
```

`serialize()` returns `param=value&param=value` etc, so you just have to add the pageRequest at the end.

---

I realized the answer (if it still not working) : Change the line

```
var pageRequest = $(this).attr('id');
```

to

```
pageRequest = $(this).attr('id');
```

There is a scoping problem here, `var pageRequest = 0;` on the top, as a global variable, but you assign `pageRequest` as a new local variable inside the click-event by using `var`, which is not visible outside - and it is the "global" `pageRequest` you want to change for use in your `submit()`.

Comment: This allows the script to run, but doesn't send over pgeNmbr with the post request for some reason. At least I don't think it does. If I send the info using a hidden form and modify the value with jQuery the pagination works, so the PHP side of things works...

Comment: Then pageRequest is not set, I assume you inserted it correct. It is not a guess, look at serialize http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ uses the above a lot to finish ajax calls with extra (often hardcoded) params. Try make a `var s=$(this).serialize()+'&pgeNmbr='+pageRequest` and log it to console.

Comment: almost embarassing no one including me saw that before :)